# Using maven-build-cache-extension and running into compatibility issues

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I guess this is relatively new, so I added this extension in my .mvn/extensions.xml

And it's complaining `[WARNING] Cache requires Maven >= 3.9, but version is 3.8.1. Disabling cache.`

But when I look for the latest maven, it's 3.8.6... there's 4.x, but it's in the beta channel and it's incompatible with v3 enforcers. Anyone resolve this in the past?

```
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-build-cache-extension</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a SNAPSHOT version instead of the release version? https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.extensions/maven-build-cache-extension

Comment: That's fair, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/apache/maven-build-cache-extension/blob/master/pom.xml#L487

The extension has this in their pom:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>maven3</id>
    <properties>
        <mavenVersion>3.9.0-SNAPSHOT</mavenVersion>
        <maven.dir>maven3</maven.dir
        <maven.basedir>${project.build.directory}/${maven.dir}</maven.basedir
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And this in the readme:

> The code currently relies on un-released modifications in the core Maven project, available both for latest 3.9.x and for 4.0-alpha-x SNAPSHOTS described in MNG-7391.

So you can run with `mvn -Pmaven3 ...` to use Maven 3.9.0-SNAPSHOT. There is no released version of Maven that will work with this extension besides >= 3.9.0.

Comment: How do I download this version? It doesn't seem available on maven website or in github

Comment: You might have to build it yourself, I don't see a posted binary anywhere. https://github.com/apache/maven/tree/maven-3.9.x#quick-build

Comment: Everything is correct except the `mvn -Pmaven3` part. This profile is for extension build purposes only and will do nothing in other projects. To run the extension need a distribution of correct version, installed locally or launched through maven wrapper.

Comment: This is pretty cool, now I don't have to build modules that don't need it. @kjsmita6 is it possible to have this in our ci as well? Or does the cache break during every build?

Comment: @AlexanderAshitkin if you know the answer, I'd also appreciate it about having this in a ci pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You’re right, at this point need to use 3.9 or 4.0 snapshots. Official snapshot builds could be found in Apache snapshots repository - https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/

Also, it is more convenient to use Maven Wrapper to bootstrap snapshot version - just point distribution url to the latest available snapshot zip.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I haven't used maven wrappers before.

Any idea when the release version will be out?